# How to take any value between second and third fowardslash

Tags: regex

I am fighting with regex syntax for taking 3rd value from string split by forwardslash (bu).

```
/globalTracking/shipment/bu/number
```

I have tried various combinations but still I am not getting a value in some specific case. The allowed values are strings and dashes. 
Due to that I have tried this syntax:

```
\/(?!\w+\/)(?!\w+\/)(?:\/[a-zA-Z\-]+\/)
```

which works only for case that the "bu" contain dash. e.g. test-bu. But in case of pure string like a "test" it will not find it.

Can you please advise the right syntax?

Thanks a lot, Reddy

Comment: You disallowed word chars only with the lookahead. Remove the two `(?!\w+\/)` lookaheads.

Comment: Why not split by `/` and get `array[3]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew If I will remove them I will get nothing, if I will remove also leading \/ and will remain only (?:\/[a-zA-Z\-]+\/) then I will get 2 values: globalTracking and bu.

Comment: It does not matter. Your approach to use lookarounds and only get a match value is too fragile. If you need to get the third part you just need to *capture* it:  [`^/(?:[^/]+/){2}([^/]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/x45QDQ/1)

Comment: Please tag your question with a language or a tool.

Comment: @revo I cannot find Axway Policy studio there

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you, this works.

Comment: @ReddySK Great, I added an answer with explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage capturng groups here:

```
^/(?:[^/]+/){2}([^/]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/x45QDQ/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `/` - a slash
- `(?:[^/]+/){2}` - a quantified non-capturing group matching two repetitions of

  - `[^/]+` - one or more chars other than `/`
  - `/` - a slash
- `([^/]+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more chars other than `/`

Answer (score 3):

Try following regular expression:

`(/+(.*?)){3}/`

Following is the code implemented in python:

```
x = '/globalTracking/shipment/bu/number'
re.search('(/+(.*?)){3}/',x).group(2)
```

Output

```
'bu'
```